# How do I read data from Ignite KV-storage using jdbc?

Tags: sql, jdbc, ignite

It is ok putting/getting data from KV-store for me, using custom class for value.

Also it is ok INSERTING/SELECTING data from table, created using jdbc. This way i'm getting cache named SQL_PUBLIC_TABLENAME.

But I can't find way to INSERT/SELECT data from KV-store using SQL queries. I've created custom value class and defined fields using @QuerySqlField annotation like that:

```
@QuerySqlField(index = true)
public Integer id;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
public String records_offset;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
public Integer session_id;
```

Then I defined cache using xml-config this way:

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
        <!-- Set a cache name. -->
        <property name="name" value="test"/>

        <property name="queryEntities">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                   <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                   <property name="valueType" value="CDR"/>
                   <property name="tableName" value="CDR"/>
                   <property name="fields">
                       <map>
                           <entry key="id" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                           <entry key="records_offset" value="java.lang.String"/>
                           <entry key="session_id" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                       </map>
                   </property>

               </bean>
           </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Set cache mode. -->
        <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

I've got cache that I can put/get data in/from, and also I can connect to Ignite using sqlline tool, where I can see CDR table (among others created throug jdbc) with `test` schema:

```
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/> !tables
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|           TABLE_CAT            |          TABLE_SCHEM           |           TABLE_NAME           |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                                | PUBLIC                         | CITY                           |
|                                | test                           | CDR                            |
|                                | PUBLIC                         | PERSON                         |
|                                | PUBLIC                         | TEST2                          |
|                                | PUBLIC                         | LOL                            |
|                                | PUBLIC                         | TEST                           |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

But I can't neither read nor put data into that CDR table:

```
    0: jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/> DROP table CDR;
Error: Table doesn't exist: CDR (state=42000,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Table doesn't exist: CDR
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:671)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:130)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute(JdbcThinStatement.java:299)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:823)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:733)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:795)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265)
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/> select * from CDR;
Error: Failed to parse query: select * from CDR (state=42000,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to parse query: select * from CDR
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:671)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:130)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute(JdbcThinStatement.java:299)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:823)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:733)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:795)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265)
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/> insert into CDR(ID,  RECORDS_OFFSET, SESSION_ID) values (23, '12', 123);
Error: Failed to parse query: insert into CDR(ID,  RECORDS_OFFSET, SESSION_ID) values (23, '12', 123) (state=42000,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to parse query: insert into CDR(ID,  RECORDS_OFFSET, SESSION_ID) values (23, '12', 123)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:671)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:130)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute(JdbcThinStatement.java:299)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:823)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:733)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:795)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265)
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/>
```

Comment: I don't think you need both annotations and queryEntities. Please try replacing queryEntities with indexedTypes.

Comment: @alamar if I don't describe queryEntities, I can't get data through jdbc.

Comment: Not if you use `setIndexedTypes()` with annotations.

Comment: @alamar setIndexedTypes() only creates index on selected fields, isn't it?

Comment: `setIndexedTypes()` accepts types which either map to SQL directly (like Integer) or which are annotated. Typical use is `setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, MyAnnotatedBean.class)` <- that is (key, value)

Comment: @alamar thx you a lot. I still wonder if there is a way to map key to a sql field to use it directly in SQL-query, not through kinda "auto-added" `_key` field

Comment: Try `setKeyFields` in QueryEntity. Supply it with name of sql field desired.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use schema name to access this table:

```
select * from "test".CDR;
```

or

select * from "test.CDR";

Also, if this won't help, try to set CacheConfiguration.setSqlSchema using uppercase, for example, "PUBLIC" and use this schema name

Comment: I wish it would be so easy: `Error: Failed to parse query: select * from test.CDR (state=42000,code=0)`

Comment: PUBLIC schema works fine to get data, but I can't insert then.

Comment: `Error: Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=insert into CDR(ID,  RECORDS_OFFSET, SESSION_ID) values (23, '12', 123), params=null] (state=50000,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=insert into CDR(ID,  RECORDS_OFFSET, SESSION_ID) values (23, '12', 123), params=null]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:671)`

Comment: I would be glad to see any example, explaining how can we insert data into cache, defined using [queryentity based configuration] (https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes#section-queryentity-based-configuration), through jdbc

Comment: You need to check logs from Ignite node, it will show the exact error.

Comment: `class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Key is missing from query`

Comment: Your cache key value is not mapped to SQL fields `<property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Integer"/>`. Please add it directly via _key, i.e. `insert into CDR(_key, ID, RECORDS_OFFSET, SESSION_ID) values (1, 23, '12', 123)`

Comment: thx a lot. How do I map cache key value to SQL manually? Is there a way to read from not-public scheme? Is there anything in docs about it?

Comment: what do I do if I want to use composite key? There is no any mentions of `_key` in docs, when discussing about inserting data through sql - https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/java-sql-api

Comment: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes#custom-keys see `setKeyFields`, `_key` is also mentioned on this page.